# How to create a map colored by distance to nearest point in R

Tags: r, cartography, distance, color

I'm new to GIS and R-- hope this question makes sense.

I have a dataframe(geo07) containing two variables that record the long/lat values for about 6000 points (mat_long & mat_lat).  These points correspond to all health centers of a certain type in the US.  I can plot the points on a US by:

```
map("worldHires","usa", xlim=c(-125,-60),ylim=c(25,52), col="gray95", fill=TRUE)
points(x=geo07$mat_lon,y=geo07$mat_lat,pch=19, col="red", cex=0.5)
```

But what I really want is to color the entire US map based on distance to the closest health center.  Conceptually, I need to break the US into points/small areas and color them based on their distance to the nearest health center.  Is this a heatmap?  Are their R functions to do this?

Comment: Would counties be small enough for your small areas to carry the message?

Comment: Looks like [Voronoi diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) on the map.

Comment: @m0nhawk: I don't think so. A Voronoi diagram shows "which health centre is closest to this point", not "how far is this point from any health centre". It would look more like a heatmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `distmap()` function in [`spatstat` package](http://www.spatstat.org/) that creates a pixel image of the distance to the points. At the provided link you will find a great tutorial for this package (including `distmap()` example).

Comment: This looks VERY promising--- thanks!  I'll followup to let you know how it works.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @jbk, did you manage to get what you want with `distmap()`? If yes - consider accepting my answer (check grey mark under votes for the answer) to remove it from "unanswered" section. If no - modify your question accordingly to your issues with `distmap()`.

Comment: So sorry--- I've had to put this problem on the back burner.  I've only now gotten back.

Comment: So sorry--- I've had to put this problem on the back burner.  I've only now gotten back.  But, I think distmat will work.  So Thanks!